Do we still need to use the CkZipW::put_OemCodePage property for applications running on Windows 10 / 11?
I would be grateful if someone can clarify something about using CkZipW::put_OemCodePage property.
According to the documentation it says:

Sets the OEM code page to be used for Unicode filenames. This property defaults to the OEM code page of the computer.

And there is an example provided here:
(Unicode C++) Create Zip with utf-8 Filenames (Unicode filenames)
Here is an extract from the example:
// To zip using utf-8 filenames, set the OemCodePage = 65001
zip.put_OemCodePage(65001);

I have tried creating a ZIP file that has Japanese file names and it appears to be fine, whether this property is specified or not. Does Windows 10 / 11 by-design now cope with UTF-8 at this level?
Put simply, do I need to continue to specify this property when creating my ZIP files?

I asked ChatGPT and it said this concerning Windows 11:

Default Encoding: Windows 11 uses UTF-16 as the default encoding for text files and strings.
UTF-8 Support: Windows 11 also supports UTF-8 system-wide, but this is a recent addition and may impact older applications that rely on non-Unicode encodings.

It said the same thing for Windows 10. So this implies that I don't need to specify this property any more.

It's not about the operating system.  It's about the capabilities of the software that will be opening the .zip and extracting.  Whatever that software is, does it need the filenames to be utf-8 or not?  It shouldn't matter to software that is using a good implementation for the zip file format.
